# How to ignore "EOF is not a function" error?

Tags: c++

I build DLL that contains external object from 3rd party DLL with

```
my3rdObject->EOF()
```

function

But my main DLL depends from **<stdio.h>** lib that contains this define

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

therefore, when compiling, an error occurs

```
error C2059: syntax error: '('
```

How to solve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0JI2.jpg)

Comment: So what would you `my3rdObject->(-1)()` expect to do?

Comment: If you need both `stdio.h` and the third-party library in your code, add` #undef EOF` after `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Well.. you might want to consider *not* naming your method EOF. If you have to: a) USe `#udef EOF` followed by `#define EOF -1`. Tho I think this will cause undefined behavior. Or could use `dlsym` and supply it with the mangled function name.

Comment: @MaryChang - Unfortunately, I do not have access to the source code of the 3rd party object, it is connected from a third-party DLL, in which all methods are hardcoded. If I could, I would naturally rename the EOF method to something else.

Comment: The description of the method from the external DLL is as follows - it accepts an integer as input - the request number, and while the cursor is running over the result - it returns <> 1.
This is an example of using the Delphi method (from the 3rd party DLL documentation) - "while sh.EOF (IndQuery) <> 1 do"

Comment: I did #undef EOF, try to re-compile, got another error .. and it already comes from another iosfwd file
https://imgur.com/a/7c2hz5d
error C2065: 'EOF': undeclared identifier

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad code.

But you could workaround it by surrounding your code calling the `EOF` method with an `#undef` and `#define` block.

Example:

```cpp
#include <My3rdObject.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

#undef EOF
int foo()
{
    My3rdObject* my3rdObject = new My3rdObject();
    my3rdObject->EOF();
    delete my3rdObject;
}
#define EOF (-1)
```

I highly recommend writing an [anti corruption layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used). This is simply the kind of code you don't want in your codebase.

Comment: I did #undef EOF, try to re-compile, got another error .. and it already comes from another iosfwd file imgur.com/a/7c2hz5d error C2065: 'EOF': undeclared identifier

Comment: You need to re-define it after finishing with it. See the last line.

Comment: Yes. I try it. But got another error https://imgur.com/a/AiioYoe

Comment: You need to put the block **everywhere** you want to use the EOF method. In all the places that references the method. In all files. Not a single place.

Comment: h-file is obtained after compilation from IDL file. In the IDL file, I specified #undef and #define around the EOF method, but it didn't help ... It looks like I can't use this DLL properly. https://imgur.com/a/nsjiseK

Comment: Yeah... Then that won't work. I still think it is possible to build an anti corruption layer. But you need a lot more effort. I'll resort to using `dlsym` in this case. But not sure what's the equivalent on Windows/MSVC.

Comment: Problem solved by rename "EOF" method to "EOF1" in *.idl file !

Answer (score 0):

Preferred solution: don't use `stdio.h`. Upgrade your C++ code from I/O in the C style to I/O in the C++ style. However, for a workaround keep reading.

---

> But my main DLL depends from **<stdio.h>** lib

No, it does not. Binary files, such as DLLs, have no dependence on source files, such as headers. Rather, the **code** for your DLL depends on the `stdio.h` **header**. More precisely, the particular source file in question uses that header.

So move the problem to another source file.

This is not sweeping the problem under the rug, but taking advantage of modularization. Create a new source file and a new header that for now will implement a single function. The header might look like the following.

```cpp
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARD_FOR_THIS_HEADER
#define INCLUDE_GUARD_FOR_THIS_HEADER

// Make sure the class in question is declared.
// Ideally, you would use a header from the third-party library, but avoid a header
// that declares the EOF member function.
class ThirdObject;

// Declare a function to wrap EOF().
// (Drop the `const` if EOF was not declared as a const member.)
int check_eof(const ThirdObject & to_check);

#endif // INCLUDE_GUARD_FOR_THIS_HEADER
```

This header can be included without inteference from `stdio.h`. The corresponding source file would also avoid interference **by not including `stdio.h`**. As long as you don't have a macro definition of `EOF` available *in this source file*, there is no problem.

```cpp
#include "the_above_header.h"
#include <ThirdParty>

int check_eof(const ThirdObject & to_check)
{
    return to_check.EOF();
}
```

Keep in mind that this function takes a reference, while the code in the question implies a pointer is being used. So the code from the question would become

```
check_eof(*my3rdObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by rename "EOF" method to "EOF1" in *.idl file !

Details here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX24R.jpg

Thanks to everyone who responded and helped!